# How do you handle drawing more flood cards than there are tiles on the board in Forbidden Island?

Tags: forbidden-island

Pretty much what it says on the tin--when you're drawing, say, 5 flood cards and there are 4 tiles left in the game, are you supposed to keep shuffling and re-drawing one of those 4, thus automatically sinking one tile per turn?

Comment: As you say.  Basically if you end drawing more flood cards than there are tiles, you're more or less doomed.  Which provides a good incentive to shore up as many tiles as you can each turn, even if they aren't key to your plans - simply because you can't afford to run out of tiles too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. From the [rule book](http://www.gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/ForbiddenIslandTM-RULES.pdf) page 8.

> **When the Flood Draw Pile Runs Out**
>
> If the Flood draw pile ever runs out, immediately shuffle the Flood discard pile and stack the cards face down to form a new Flood draw pile. If this happens in the middle of a turn, continue drawing Flood cards as necessary from the new pile.

Comment: Thanks--just wanted to be sure that it accelerated into auto-doom & there wasn't some contingency I was missing.